# Translated Buttons not giving correct results

Tags: android, animation, button, onclick

I am having a button in my activity and using a TranslateAnimation to change its position.

I am using anim.setFillAfter(true); to keep the resulting translation, the button shifts its position but the touch area remains same. 
Now when i touch on the button it doesn't work rather touching on the previous location of the button calls its listener..

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Animation anim=new TranslateAnimation(0, 100, 0, 0);
        anim.setDuration(500);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        Button mybtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        mybtn.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    public void myFunc(View v){
        Toast.makeText(this, "btn clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" 
                android:onClick="myFunc"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you try removing the animation and trying ?

Comment: achually i want the button to animate to the other position and also perform its click property there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-generated your case and it seems like only 50% of the button shows the selected color. Is that right ? Try this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button sampleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    sampleButton.animate().translationX(somevalue).setDuration(someduration);
}
```

Comment: mybtn.getWidth() returns 0 in the above code and if it were returning the width of the button then also i think that clicking adjacent left to the button will work.

Comment: to get the width of the button do this : 
    mybtn.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
        anim=new TranslateAnimation(0, mybtn.getWidth(), 0, 0);
      }
    }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886624/animation-setfillafter-before-do-they-work-what-are-they-for, the answer for this question says that setFillAfter only apply to animation properties, not View properties. How can we change the view properties same as animation properties? is my question...

Comment: You could refer to this : http://graphics-geek.blogspot.com/2011/08/mysterious-behavior-of-fillbefore.html

Comment: thanks @lokoko for answering and i have found the answer to the query turns out property animation is required to animate buttons properly..

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my query at this page
[vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html#animations_viewpropertyanimator)
and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) android has explained it, buttons require a property animation not just the view animation:

Here is the code that I used:

```
Button mybtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
mybtn.animate().translationX(400).setDuration(500);
```

Thanx for your help...
I am leaving this post if anyone else require assistance.