# Detecting which View was tapped, after animating its position

Tags: android, animation, touch, viewgroup, translate-animation

I have a ScrollView which contains a RelativeLayout. The RelativeLayout contains some other viewgroups which are initially all positioned in the same place (On top of one another). A swipe down gesture pushes these viewgroups down so that the top 150px of each can be seen, by using a TranslateAnimation (Top card moves to the bottom of the screen, next card down is 150px upwards of that etc).

I have attached a touch listener to each viewgroup, which does seemingly get fired, however it only fires when I tap on the original location of the viewgroup, not where it has been moved to.  And seeing as they were all originally on top of each other, I only ever get the top viewgroup in the OnTouch method anyway.

How can I get the view to actually be in it's new location after animating?

CODE:

```
private void setViewgroupVerticalPosition(ViewGroup cardViewGroup,
        int position) {
    // Animates the ViewGroup to the correct vertical position.
    TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, position);
    ta.setDuration(500);
    ta.setFillAfter(true);
    ta.setAnimationListener(this);
    cardViewGroup.startAnimation(ta);
    /*
    cardViewGroup.layout(cardViewGroup.getLeft(), position, cardViewGroup.getRight(), position + (cardViewGroup.getBottom() - cardViewGroup.getTop()));
    cardViewGroup.forceLayout();
    cardViewGroup.invalidate();
    */
}
```

After this has been run on each ViewGroup tapping in the original position is the only way to trigger the OnTouch event...

Comment: Are you using `fillAfter` with your `TranslateAnimation`?

Comment: Yes :S - I will put code samples on the question to see if it's anything stupidly coded...

Comment: Can you imagine living without `fillAfter`, instead having the `AnimationListener` set the final position once the animation ended? I've heard that the use of `fillAfter` is known to cause this problem with transfomrations.

Comment: Any idea how to set the position of my ViewGroup inside the relative layout in the AnimationEnded handler? (Also how to get a reference to the correct viewgroup)

Comment: It sounds to me as if you just need a reference to the RelativeLayout and the ViewGroup? I'm not aware of the difficulties you are facing. When you initiate the animation, you must surely know both objects. How about the listener having a method with which you can set both references?

Comment: I have many ViewGroups, instantiating a specific listener for each is surely the wrong way to go about things?  And it's irrelevant as there's n way to position a ViewGroup as far as I can see?  ViewGroup has no setY() method to set it's vertical position.

Comment: Your animation listener gets the Animation in question as a parameter, right? So you could either subclass the Animation to include an identification of the ViewGroup and the RelativeLayout, or you associate Animations with their objects using a Map. Regarding the positioning... I was expecting that you could describe the final destination of your ViewGroup also with gravity, margin, padding? It should be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of android you're developing for you might have unexpected results with your animations. See this question and responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886624/animation-setfillafter-before-do-they-work-what-are-they-for). Note Chet Haase's comments in particular.

Comment: I actually had read this, but didn't think it applied as the apparent (visible) location of my ViewGroup is where I'd animated it to, it's just where the touch handling section of the viewgroup is that hasn't moved.  Regardless, I'm not sure how to position my ViewGroup manually.  There's no setTop() method or similar as far as I can see?