# Translation animation for hiding View

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, android-view

I need my listview to hide and show using alternative touches. Hence for hiding the listview on the left side of the screen am using animation

```
 Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(-100, 0,0, 0);
                            animation.setDuration(100);
                            animation.setFillAfter(true);
                            lv.startAnimation(animation);
                            lv.setVisibility(0);
```

and for displaying am using

```
lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

My problem is list view is not getting hide. It will go leftside and coming back again. I don't know how to hide listview to the left edge completely on touch. Please help in achieving this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i find the answer and it is very simple modification in co-ordinate values. And the code is

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,-200,0, 0);
                    animation.setDuration(2000);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    listView1.startAnimation(animation);
                    listView1.setVisibility(0);
```

Here am setting negative value at second co-ordinate cause from o it is moving twowards negative side which means the view is moving twowards inner left side.

Answer (score 22):

```
// To animate view slide out from left to right
public void slideToRight(View view){
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,view.getWidth(),0,0);
animate.setDuration(500);
animate.setFillAfter(true);
view.startAnimation(animate);
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
// To animate view slide out from right to left
public void slideToLeft(View view){
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,-view.getWidth(),0,0);
animate.setDuration(500);
animate.setFillAfter(true);
view.startAnimation(animate);
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

// To animate view slide out from top to bottom
public void slideToBottom(View view){
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,view.getHeight());
animate.setDuration(500);
animate.setFillAfter(true);
view.startAnimation(animate);
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

// To animate view slide out from bottom to top
public void slideToTop(View view){
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-view.getHeight());
animate.setDuration(500);
animate.setFillAfter(true);
view.startAnimation(animate);
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: What i want is i need my view to hide from left side to interior left side and hence i declared negative value. this is to move from one end to the another.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to **hide** your View, use

```
View.INVISIBLE // constant value 4
```

or

```
View.GONE // constant value 8
```

**You are currently using the value 0** which is the constant value of `View.VISIBLE`.

I suppose you want to hide the ListView after animating it?

**But you are showing the ListView directly after starting the animation.** Take a look at **AnimationListener** and hide the ListView

```
onAnimationEnd(...)
```

For example:

```
// assuming the listview is currently visible
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(-100, 0,0, 0);
                            animation.setDuration(100);
                            animation.setFillAfter(true);

animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                     lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

lv.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: The view is not hided completely instead it is coming back.I need it to hide completely on the interior left side.

Comment: Then you need to increase the distance of the animation. Probably set it to the width of your display.

Answer (score 0):

for the general understanding of what you don't know, i found you another post that explains it very good!! The View and its animation work a bit different as it might be expected!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5888969/2074990

Comment: Its about fill. I need to hide the view on touch