# How to animate a drawable bar graph to look like its growing?

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, layout

I am trying to make a bar graph that increases in size with each players score. Everytime a button is pressed to indicate who got the points, the bar increases relative to the points. So far I have been able to set up a layout the way I want, I'm just having issues updating it programmatically. Here is my Layout XML. It is a lot of nested layouts so that it works on a wide range of screens.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/letterbutton" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/letterButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="A"
                android:textSize="115dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nextScore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="5 Pts"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Score1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0 Pts"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/scoreBar1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/layout1_bg" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Score2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0 Pts"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/scoreBar2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/layout2_bg" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Score3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0 Pts"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/scoreBar3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/layout3_bg" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Score4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0 Pts"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/scoreBar4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:layout_margin="6dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/layout4_bg" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="updateInfo"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:text="Button"
                android:background="@drawable/custombutton1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="updateInfo"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:text="Button"
                android:background="@drawable/custombutton2"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="updateInfo"
                android:text="Button"
                android:background="@drawable/custombutton3"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="updateInfo"
                android:text="Button"
                android:background="@drawable/custombutton4"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code handling buttons and where I would put the code to resize/animate the bars "growing" in size.

```
public void updateInfo(View v){

        if (AlphaButton.getPosition() < 26) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.button1){
                TextView mytextview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score1);
                mytextview1.setText(AlphaButton.addScore(1) + " Pts");
                TextView mytextview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nextScore);
                mytextview2.setText(Integer.toString(AlphaButton.getPoints()) + " Pts");
                ImageView rotatebtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                rotatebtn.setRotation(angle);
                angle += 13.846;
            }else if (v.getId() == R.id.button2){
                TextView mytextview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score2);
                mytextview1.setText(AlphaButton.addScore(2) + " Pts");
                TextView mytextview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nextScore);
                mytextview2.setText(Integer.toString(AlphaButton.getPoints()) + " Pts");
                ImageView rotatebtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                rotatebtn.setRotation(angle);
                angle += 13.846;
            }else if (v.getId() == R.id.button3){
                TextView mytextview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score3);
                mytextview1.setText(AlphaButton.addScore(3) + " Pts");
                TextView mytextview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nextScore);
                mytextview2.setText(Integer.toString(AlphaButton.getPoints()) + " Pts");
                ImageView rotatebtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                rotatebtn.setRotation(angle);
                angle += 13.846;
            }else if (v.getId() == R.id.button4){
                TextView mytextview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score4);
                mytextview1.setText(AlphaButton.addScore(4) + " Pts");
                TextView mytextview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nextScore);
                mytextview2.setText(Integer.toString(AlphaButton.getPoints()) + " Pts");
                ImageView rotatebtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                rotatebtn.setRotation(angle);
                angle += 13.846;
            }
            TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.letterButton);
            myTextView.setText(AlphaButton.getString());
```

I have exhausted many hours at this point trying all kinds of methods in the view class to update the height of the bars with plenty of problems with each attempt. I have yet to find anything that works the way I want. I appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To start with, it is not a good idea to have several weighted nested LinearaLayout's. That can lead to poor performance. Weighted layouts need to be measured twice, so when you nest them, the number of measurements increases exponentially.

As far as changing the size of the bars, it depends. If you just want to change the size, you can change the view's LayoutParams.

Another Option would be to use a ScaleAnimation.

```
 ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 0, 1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5,    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0.5);
 animation.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
 animation.setFillAfter(true);
 myView.startAnimation(animation);
```

The first 4 params of the scale animation are the start and end float values for  x and y with 1f representing 100% of the current size.

If you go this route I would recommend reading up on what setFillAfter() does, it may save you trouble down the road. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/5888969/3430469.

Comment: I appreciate the help, thank you. I'll try the ScaleAnimation tonight. Instead of weighted, nested LinearLayouts, what is a good choice? I have been trying to make an activity that scales to most screen sizes so as not to have to make several different layouts.