# TextViews animation onClickListener

Tags: java, android, textview, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I animated a LinearLayout to make it like "live news", like this.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_live_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|start|left"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>
```

Inside that LinearLayout there are several LinearLayout constituted by 2 TextViews(Title and Description)...

```
<LinearLayout>
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/live_tv_back_color"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:paddingEnd="25dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="25dp"
android:paddingStart="2dp"
android:paddingTop="2dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_news_tile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/live_tv_title_color"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_news_msg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/live_tv_text_color"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to put OnclickListener on the childs of first layout, like this...

```
for(int i=0;i<news.getChildCount();i++){
        news.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TeamNews team_new = team_news_factory.getTeamView((String) v.getTag());

                FragmentNews fragment = FragmentNews.newInstance(team_new.getSqlitePk());
                fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), Home.class.getName());
            }
        });
    }
```

i tried aswell put in the TextViews(Title and Description)

```
OnClickListener myClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TeamNews team_new = team_news_factory.getTeamView((String) v.getTag());

            FragmentNews fragment = FragmentNews.newInstance(team_new.getSqlitePk());
            fragment.show(man, FragmentLiveNews.class.getName());
        }
};

((TextView) ll_new.findViewById(R.id.tv_news_title)).setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
((TextView) ll_new.findViewById(R.id.tv_news_msg)).setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
```

The problem is that the onClickListener is triggering by the the postions that the elements were made and not throw the animation, per example, if the text views is in the middle of the screen it will not trigger onClickListener if I click on it, but will trigger if i click were it was created(left).

This is the code to the animation:

```
Animation _anim = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);
    _anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    _anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    _anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    _anim.setDuration(news.getSize() * 20);
    _anim.setFillBefore(false);
    _anim.setFillEnabled(true);
```

I use this code the animate the LinearLayout(ll_live_tv) and the LinearLayout with the news(title and message/content), and still the views(title and message/content) are static and don't follow the animation. When i click on them they don't trigger the setOnClickListener, just in the position that they were created.

Hope you guys understood what i'm trying to accomplish.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using Android Animation class, those animations wont actually change the position of the animating view, translation will be just an visual effect, unless you specify that you want to change state of the view. You have to use methods/Flags like `setFillAfter(boolean fillAfter)` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html#setFillAfter(boolean) and `setFillBefore(boolean fillBefore)` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html#setFillBefore(boolean). `setFillAfter(true)` will change actual position of view

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886624/animation-setfillafter-before-do-they-work-what-are-they-for

Comment: @vakman, thaks for the comment. My problemis exacly as mention, my views are static but the animation is moving. So i cannot click when they far from ther criation position.
I saw the "setFill()s" but couldn't manage to click in the textviews wherever they are. Do you have any guess?

Comment: Can you show the animation code?

Comment: @vakman yes, i will edit the post

Comment: @vakman, edited and thank you for your time

Comment: I would suggest you to use `PropertyAnimator` https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html instead of `TranslationAnimation` . Propery animator was developed for solving your kind of scenario.

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try :)